# Changing Slack bot name / image using Slash Commands?

Tags: python, http, slack, slash

I'm setting up a slackbot with slash commands and according to API you're able to pass username to set the username of a bot. When I try it, the name does not update. Does this not work with slash commands in the same way that it does with bots?

```
from bottle import run, post, request
@post('/hello')
def hello():
    mydict = request.forms.get('text')
    response = {
    "username": "test",
    "response_type": "in_channel",
    "text": "Greetings!"
        }
    return response
```

matt [11:00 AM]
/hello

MyBot APP [11:00 AM]
Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Correct. You can not change the name of the app that appears on Slack when you respond to a request like that. It will always show the name you configured in the app settings.

However, there is a workaround for your use case: Instead of replying to the received request directly you can send a message into the channel / to the user with [chat.postMessage](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage), which will allow you to specify a custom username and icon.